# Two Select with multiple column statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to join these two SQL Statement into one. I want the end result to be all in one query... if possible.

```
SELECT  WHM_ilvl AS BestWHM_ilvl, username AS BestWHM_Name FROM roster ORDER BY WHM_ilvl DESC
SELECT  BLM_ilvl AS BestBLM_ilvl, username AS BestBLM_Name FROM roster ORDER BY BLM_ilvl DESC
```

The result would be like this:

```
BestWHM_ilvl | BestWHM_ilvl | BestBLM_ilvl | BestBLM_ilvl
107          | User1        | 121          | user2
102          | User11       | 109          | user3
80           | User3        | 101          | user52
79           | User7        | 99           | user3
78           | User4        | 80           | user1
```

I tried with () separating them and including them as if they were single column but it doesn't work. I tried looking for the same type of query I want but never found anything.

I don't mind being referred to the right knowledge if available.

I'm using this with PHP and MySQL.

regards,

Comment: If I understand it right, the two couples of columns do not correspond with each other in one row. I suggest keeping results of these two selects as separate values and in PHP use them to create one table. It won't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  r1.WHM_ilvl AS BestWHM_ilvl
, r1.username AS BestWHM_Name
, r2.BLM_ilvl AS BestBLM_ilvl
, r2.username AS BestBLM_Name
FROM roster r1
  JOIN roster r2 ON r1.id = r2.id
ORDER BY r1.WHM_ilvl, r2.BLM_ilvl
DESC
```

Here's the simplest form of the query of what you are asking for given what is in the question. There seems like there may be more to it than that, if so update and I will try an come back to this.

**EDIT** Oops. Corrected a couple of things I should've caught beforehand.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as is. it first told me that "rost" doesn't exist and if I correct it to "roster", it tell me that WHM_ilvl is ambiguous.

Also, I'm not sure I understand this statement, care to explain? The goal is to get the name for each of the user and their score. In the original table, the column "Username" is there only once and the column "xxx_ilvl" once as well. I will repeat this for each column to get the ranking in each.